# Creating Rails submit forms for related records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a list of invoices (model: Invoice) to be sold. For each invoice (view: index) I want people to be able make an offer (model: Offer) for the invoice with a submit form. How can I create a form for each invoice to make an offer?

```
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>      
    # put a form for each invoice to create a new invoice.offer 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

1. [railscasts - nested-model-form-part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1),  and
2. [railscasts - nested-model-form-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)